# how to record realtime keyframes with external input for loc/rot/scale

Tags: keyframes

I am trying to animate a human head with the auto keying function. This works if i adjust the values of loc/rot/scale manually by mouse or keyboard.

But i'm using a plugin with face recognition to move the head but there aren't any keyframes generated. the plugin changes the values of the loc/rot/scale directly but the numbers are orange instead of green or yellow when altered. (yellow is created keyframe)

while trying to edit when playing the timeline the head just want's to go back to the last keyframe position instead of creating a new one, hence a very disturbing flikkering between a new position and the position of the last keyframe.

anyone any idea how to solve this?
Thanks

video of issue:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/GYtUREB4pCsNkAMB7

Comment: have you tried turning on auto keyframes?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the video the button is on but it isn't making new keyframes with the auto keyframe enabled. Also i can't find very many settings about it. I just want it to record everything always but it only makes manual keyframes